# Count and sum consecutive duplicate numbers

Tags: arrays, matlab

How to sum only consecutive duplicate numbers in order to find a unique value? for example, I have a vector

```
A = [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]
```

then when summing only consecutive duplicate numbers, I will have

```
B = [0 1 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 1]
```

finally the number of unique values different from `0` and `1` :

```
sum(B>1)
```

I know one way to solve the problem:

```
sum(diff(find(A==1))==1)
```

but it seems it is not a good method.

Comment: Are there just ones and zeros?

Comment: yes,only ones and zeros

Comment: If ` sum(diff(find(A==1))==1)` does what you want I don't see a reason, why it shouldn't be a good solution. What don't you like about it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is because I can see the vector B and know the unique value is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution:

```
A = [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]

%// get Islands
a = cumsum(~A)
b = a(logical(A))
%// count occurences 
c = histc(b,unique(b))
%// count number of occurences > 1 
d = sum(c > 1)
%// or sum of occurences > 1  
e = sum(c(c > 1))
```

---

```
c =
     1     1     2     1     1
d =
     1
e = 
     2
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the total number of repeated values in the array including "0" values.

```
sum(A(1:end-1)-A(2:end)==0)

ans =
 7
```

If you are interested only in the repeated "1" values, you can change it to

```
sum(A(1:end-1)+A(2:end)==2)

ans =
 1
```

Note that this is the count of duplicates if you have `[1 1 1]` you'll get 2 not 1.

Comment: I am only interested in repeated and consecutive ''1'' values, then sum them together in the above case is 2

Comment: Thanks, the answer from "thewaywewalk" works fine, since I can know the number of unique values and the corresponding values.